# persistencia en LocalStorage (arreglos)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist, local-storage

tengo el siguiente código, lo que quiero es guardar un array en mi localStorage, que se vayan guardando de 1 en uno conforme los vaya agregando, hasta el momento esto es lo que tengo, si guarda el primer item en el local, pero ya a partir del segundo, se empieza a sobre escribir en la misma posición.
Saludos Colegas

```js
function datos(idx,model){
    
    var fanIdx  = new Array();
    var fanModel = new Array();


    var datos  = [];
    var objeto = {};

var datosLocal = localStorage.getItem('datos');
datosArray = JSON.parse(datosLocal);

if(datosLocal != null) {
for(var i = 0; i < datosArray.length; i++) {
    //agregamos el item después del que ya se a agregado
   datosArray.push({ 
        "fanIdx"    : idx,
        "fanModel"  : model 
    });
  }
  
}else{
   //agregamos el primer item
   datos.push({ 
        "fanIdx"    : idx,
        "fanModel"  : model 
        });
    
}
    
objeto.datos = datos;

console.log(datosArray)
localStorage.setItem("datos", JSON.stringify(objeto));
//console.log(JSON.stringify(objeto));

}

$(document).ready(function() {
datos(0,'5SILENT100');
 //datos(1,'5SILENT200');
 //datos(2,'5SILENT300');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `datos` del `localStorage` finalmente queda de la siguiente manera. Tiene la propiedad `datos`, que es un array de objetos, en cada objeto tiene las propiedades `fanIdx`, que es un entero, y `fanModel` que es un `String`:

```
{
    "datos": [
        {"fanIdx":0,"fanModel":"5SILENT100"},
        {"fanIdx":1,"fanModel":"5SILENT200"},
        {"fanIdx":2,"fanModel":"5SILENT300"}
    ]
}
```

Es decir, las variables `fanIdx` y `fanModel` no son arrays, sino que son variables de tipo primitivo. Tampoco es necesario declarar esas variables porque se pueden asignar directamente al objeto.

Uso un operador ternario para asignar un valor al objeto. Si al existir la variable en `localStorage`, asigno los valores de la variable, de lo contrario, le asigno un objeto predeterminado, sin valores.

Es decir:

```
var objeto = si pasa esto ? hago esto : si no, hago esto otro
```

Para este ejemplo es:

```
var objeto = datosLocal==null?{datos:[]}:JSON.parse(datosLocal)
```

Luego hago `push`, sea cual sea el caso anterior, es decir, lo que antes estaba dentro del `if` y también dentro del `else`, al estar de los dos lados hace que siempre se ejecute, entonces lo paso fuera de la estructura del condicional como un solo `push`, inmediatamente luego de declarar el `objeto` con sus valores.

Por último guardo en `localStorage` el objeto.

Código:

```
function datos(idx,model) {

    var datosLocal = localStorage.getItem('datos')
    var objeto = datosLocal==null?{datos:[]}:JSON.parse(datosLocal)
    objeto.datos.push({"fanIdx": idx,"fanModel": model})
    localStorage.setItem("datos", JSON.stringify(objeto))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('datos'))
}
datos(0,'5SILENT100')
datos(1,'5SILENT200')
datos(2,'5SILENT300')
```